# Certificate's private key is exported as a different value?

Tags: c#, ssl, openssl, cryptography, certificate

I have created  a self-signed-certificate (`pfx`) for testing purposes.

I'm able to export ist public key via :

```
X509Certificate2 cer = new X509Certificate2();
X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

var certificateCollection = store.Certificates.Find(...);
var cert = certificateCollection[0] ;
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToBase64String(cert.Export( X509ContentType.Cert ), Base64FormattingOptions.InsertLineBreaks));
```

Result  :

```
MIIDFTCCAf2gAw...........eFUpBB9C0/UNRmD7EAg==
```

This is consistent with `openssl` command :

```
$ openssl pkcs12 -in domain.name.pfx -clcerts -nokeys -out domain.name.crt
```

Result :

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIDFTCCAf2gAw........9C0/UNRmD7EAg==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

However , when I export the *private* key via C# :

```
Convert.ToBase64String(cert.Export( X509ContentType.Pfx ), Base64FormattingOptions.InsertLineBreaks)
```

I get :

```
MIIDFTCCAf2gAw............OVeFUpBB9C0/UNRmD7EAg==
```

While with `openssl` command :

```
$ openssl pkcs12 -in domain.name.pfx -nocerts -nodes -out domain.name.key
```

I get  :

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEvQIBADANBgkqhkiG9w.........6HNjF2h7uuFdvbH2VAVg=
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

**Question:**

Why do I get different results in the private keys ? And how can I fix my C# code to yield the same result as openssl's result ?

(NB - I'm not talking about `-----begin/end keys-----` boundries , but the actual value.

Additional info  , [the PFX file](https://files.fm/u/sfc76pjv)

Comment: what happens when you skip the openssl param "-nodes" and actually provide the same password for encryption?

Comment: @DarkSquirrel42 I get an error https://i.stack.imgur.com/joj8y.png

Comment: ok... openssl has a 4 char minimum for the password... as you can read in the error msg...

Comment: @DarkSquirrel42 I will try to export the self signed with "1234" password and will update the question.

Comment: @DarkSquirrel42 I get different results , still. I've added the pfx file to the question.

Comment: hmm ... according to the msdn class documentation, export(...) will export the certificate and the private key to a byte array ... try skipping "-nocert" on the openssl side ...

Comment: @DarkSquirrel42 is there anyway to export only the private key so that it will have identical values ?

Comment: you can take the PrivateKey Porpoerty, which will hold a CryptoServiceProvider, extract the key alone from that, transform it into ASN.1 DER format, and encode the bytes of your ASN.1 structure as base64

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `X509ContentType.Cert` representation is the same because the certificate is a static structure. If you export it in a loop you'll always get the same answer.

The `X509ContentType.Pfx` representation is different because there are random salts in the PFX structure. One for each certificate, one for each private key, and one final one.  If you export the same public+private pair as a PFX in a loop it will be different every time (288 bits of random data).

The end of the base64 data is different because it contains the last salt and the MAC over the rest of the data (including the encrypted cert salt and the encrypted key salt). It also contains an integer work factor, which Windows chooses as 2000 and OpenSSL chooses as 2048; further differentiating the OpenSSL and Windows exports.

So what you are seeing is by design. If you need a stable export you'll have to do something else. If you were just concerned that they're different, it's almost certainly fine.

Comment: These outputs are different because one is private key and the other is PFX. It does not matter what the salt is. There is no salt in the openssl export.

Answer (score 1):

> Why do I get different results in the private keys ?

You are trying to do two separate things. With openssl you are using pfx file that contains private key and certificate(s). In c# you are using some representation of certificate with private key and you are doing export to a pfx file!

> And how can I fix my C# code to yield the same result as openssl's result ?

C# has no friendly function that could export only private key (in openssl-like way) from X509Certificate2. As @darksquirell42 mentioned in comments you could use `X509Certificate2.PrivateKey` property, then cast it to `RSACryptoServiceProvider` and do [`ToXmlString(true)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsa.toxmlstring(v=vs.110).aspx). But this will give you private key parameters in a xml structure. Then you would have to take each parameter and construct an ASN.1 structure [PKCS#1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8017#appendix-A.1.2) or (IMHO better) [PKCS#8](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5208#page-5). But C# has by default no friendly methods to work with ASN.1 objects.

OR you could use some crypto library to do it for you like BouncyCastle. [This method](https://github.com/bcgit/bc-csharp/blob/b19e68a517e56ef08cd2e50df4dcb8a96ddbe507/crypto/src/security/DotNetUtilities.cs#L109) from BouncyCastle could be helpful.

Comment: @Royi Could you un-base64 these two private keys and use ASN.1 editor to look what is different? Could be that one is PKCS#1 and the other is PKCS#8.